# Count unique values that match a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the following formula in Excel to count the unique values within a column.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FREQUENCY(MATCH(B3:B12,B3:B12,0),ROW(B3:B12)-ROW(B3)+1)>0))
```

I want to expand on that slightly and count the unique values from column B that match column J's value of "United Kingdom".

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(J3:J13="United Kingdom",MATCH(B3:B13,B3:B13,0)),ROW(B3:B13)-ROW(B3)+1)>0))
```

Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Cool, thanks, that seems like it's not far off but getting an error at the moment. I've amended it to match my real example `=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(D2:D46513="United Kingdom",MATCH(D2:D46513,D2:D46513,0)),ROW(D2:D46513)-ROW(D2)+1)>0))`

Comment: Sorry pasted in the wrong part, still got an error but at least it's referencing the right thing `=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(J2:J46513="United Kingdom",MATCH(D2:D46513,D2:D46513,0)),ROW(D2:D46513)-ROW(D2)+1)>0))`

Comment: Just to be sure; you entered as array?

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow, I've just pasted in the formula into a cell. The data is just thousands of rows and around 12 columns

Comment: It's an array formula meaning you'll have to confirm through Ctrl shift enter instead of just enter